# Change Log for Admin Panel Design of WordPress

Tags: version-control, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a change log specifically for the WordPress admin panel? I'd like to know the design changes of the admin panel through different versions since v3.0.

I may find them by installing each version on my local server but it's too much work. If I could find when styles were changed, I can just install the changed versions.

Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in particular, no.

You can view the [Wordpress Changelogs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:Changelogs), but many (if not all) of them don't address the style changes to the Wordpress Core. For the most part, it deals mainly with functionality changes, bug fixes, and database upgrades.

[Wordpress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) also has a lot of useful information on Trouble Tickets submitted and addressed, but also does not deal primarily with Style changes.

I've filtered the Trac Timeline to all of the changesets within the past year, so hopefully this will get started on what you're looking for:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/timeline?from=09%2F12%2F12&daysback=365&authors=&changeset=on&update=Update

Comment: Thanks. How do I find the version number? For example, in the last page of the link you provided, I highlighted the word `CSS` in my browser and found `Changeset [21461] by azaozz` and opened it. It looks like indicating style changes of admin panel. But I cannot find the WordPress version number of it. I'm new to view logs like this so your additional information would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wordpress' Trac records doesn't account for version number. Your best bet is to cross reference the dates of the given Changesets with the [dates of the previous versions of Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions)